# How can profiling agg in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I created a SQL function and put it at GROUP BY , HAVING clause, but I found the agg function takes too much time. the query plan is here

http://explain.depesz.com/s/ooaM

The functions should not be so slow, I want to understand why it takes so long. Could anyone suggest some tools I can use to profile postgresql? I'm working on pg9.4 and as I'm working on its source code, I would like to understand its internal. Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code of your `calc_area` function

Comment: lack of statistics. (or: orverly skew destributions. Or : bad datamodel)

Comment: it's really a foreign FOREIGN DATA WRAP using a third party API to calculate areas. The input is face id, output is area in double precision.  @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @wildplasser I do not know what's the HashAggregate doing, doesn't it should be evaluate all calc_area function on target list?

Comment: Wihout the actual query and the definition of the relevant tables (including PK/FK and secondary indexes), *plus* a description of your intentions, nothing can be optimised. Third party's API's can only be optimised by the third  parties themselves.

Comment: Foreign data wrappers are only for tables - you can't define a *function* through a foreign data wrapper

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to perform detailed machine-instruction level instrumentation on postgres, you can use `valgrind`.

Specifically, you can use the following command.

`valgrind --tool=callgrind --dump-instr=yes --trace-jump=yes ./postgres -D your_data_dir`

Note that such instrumentation requires postgres to be compiled with `-g`, i.e., in your `configure` command, you need to do `configure --enable-debug`.

Then you can start a client session as regular: `psql database_name`.
And then type in the query to execute. (Note that on a CPU-heavy query that involves aggregates, the profile can result in a significant slow down. So you probably should take a small sample of your data for profile purpose.)

After the execution finishes, there will be multiple output files produced by `valgrind`, namely `callgrind.$pid.out`, in which the `$pid` is the process ID of all postgres' processes, including backend and the one the responsible for handling the client session where you ran your query. Let's assume the pid for that process is `12345`, what you need to do next is to convert that raw profile output file into a human-readable representation. You will use the following command.

`callgrind_annotate --auto=yes callgrind.12345.out > profie.txt`